# Plotting boundary of 3d topographical plot on a 2D line

Tags: plotting

I have a table consisting of the points of the following plot:
[image]

Which looks like this from the top:
[image]

I would like to plot a line connecting all the dots of the boundary in the first picture, so that I have a 2d plot showing the the variation of height in the topograpghy.
The code used for the generation of the plot is a little complicated so I do not want to post the whole code here. If I wanted to plot, say, the boundary of

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

using a line, how would I be able to do this?
The coordinates for this plot can be found on this link:
https://dpaste.org/kORh
Warning": This is quite a large file.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: "The code used for the generation of the plot is a little complicated so I do not want to post the whole code here." That's fine, post the **values** instead. I am afraid that the alternative example you propose may not be representative of your actual problem.

Comment: The data I have used is from actual surface topography of the skin and was processed using grid points. It's a really long table full of coordinates.@MarcoB should I still post it?

Comment: Yes, but since it's so long, it may be better to link to it. Since it's text only, use https://pastebin.com/ and then edit your question to add the link to the data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "boundary".

Comment: @ChrisK: By "boundary" , I mean a line connecting all the edge points on one face  of the plot. For this example, it will be a sinusoidal-like plot due to the large degree of undulations at the surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `elevation` defined as your provided data, we can extract the points at the "boundary" / side with the minimum value of $x$:

```
flat = elevation~Flatten~1;

ListLinePlot[
  With[{min = Min[flat[[All, 1]]]},
    Cases[flat, {x_, y_, z_} /; x == min :> {y, z}]
  ],
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: boundary corresponding to the min values of x]

Appropriate modifications to this code should give you any of the other three possibilities, i.e. max value of $x$, and min/max value of $y$.

Comment: You are simply magnificent. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IfIcantdoit Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

Plot the elevation for every tenth `x` slice (first plot is the same as @MarcoB's). The `Part` specification can be changed to slice along other axes.

```
elevation[[1 ;; ;; 10, All, 2 ;; 3]] //
   Map[ListLinePlot[#, Axes -> False, Frame -> True] &] //
   Partition[#, UpTo@7] & //
   Grid
```

[image]

---

Not an answer, just some other ways of visualizing the data.

Neat, it does look like skin (using `flat` from @MarcoB's answer).

```
ListDensityPlot[flat, ColorFunction -> "GrayTones"]
```

[image]

```
ListContourPlot[flat]
```

[image]

Comment: It is skin! My project is the effect of collagen fibres on the stress response of skin. Some interesting stuff. Thank you for your contribution - I have a presentation tomorrow to the head of continuum mechanics at university and this definitely shall help with the visualization of data.